# Run all JUnit tests with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Java application which uses Gradle as build system. This is multi-project built (several Java projects).

When I run `gradlew test` and some of the tests are failing I've noticed not all tests actually run.

If I add the following code to `build.gradle` it does run all tests but of course, the built always complete successfully:

```
test {
    ignoreFailures = true
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Does gradle stop executing tests after the first failure?
2. Is there a way to run all tests (even when some fail) and still have the built fail if some of them failed?

Answer (score 6):

Gradle offers the --continue parameter `gradlew build --continue` which executes all tasks regardless of their success. However, if any executed task failed the whole build is marked as failed.

I think you are looking for that switch.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are running tests from the root of you project.

The `test` task is part of Java Plugin for Gradle. As from the official documentation:

Projects with large test suites can take a long time to execute even though a failure occurred early on leading to unnecessary wait times (especially on CI). To short circuit this behavior, the Test.getFailFast() property allows you to cause the test task to fail after the first test failure instead of running all tests. When this property is true, the resulting output will only show the results of tests that have completed up to and including the failure. To enable this fail fast behavior in your build file, set the failFast property to true:

```
test {
    failFast = true
}
```

The --fail-fast command line option enables the behavior from the command line. An invocation looks like:

```
gradle test --fail-fast
```

The default value for the failFast property is false.

Official documentation can be found [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_test).

So to answer your questions:

1. By default, Gradle does not stop executing tests after the first failure. This behaviour can be modified using failFast property.
2. Default behaviour should do the trick. By running `gradle test` all tests will be run. If any of them fail, the build will fail. Since you have a multi-project build, make sure you are running Gradle from your root project.

Comment: I am running it from the root project. It is a closed source project so I can’t show the code but I’m sure the number of tasks to execute is different. I’ll try your suggestions. Thank you

Comment: @IdoRan please let us know what was the problem (once you solve it). Also, u can accept this answer if it answered all your questions.